# "Нам ценно ваше мнение"

Tags: грамотная-речь

После разговора с оператором и оценки услышал и резануло слух:

> Нам очень ценно ваше мнение.

Разве так правильно говорить? По-моему, *ценно* может быть только объективной оценкой.

Хотя, может быть, в этом я и неправ, потому что, с другой стороны, можно сказать "мы ценим" или "я ценю".

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 3):

Вместо расширенного комментария.

В монографии Н.Ю. Шведовой "Русская грамматика", 1980 г., сказано, что управление прилагательного "ценный" вариативно (кому-чему-н. — для кого-чего-н.) и даже объясняется, по каким причинам эта вариативность со временем возрастает. В книге "Грамматика русского языка в упражнениях и комментариях" О.И. Глазуновой приводится пример управления с ДП. И в других добротных источниках тоже.

**Дополнение.**

Добавлю побольше примеров из Нацкорпуса с различными оттенками значения слова *ценный*. Я привожу не все цитаты. Отдельно замечу, что подобных примеров с прилагательным *важный* намного больше.

> Я выудил у него ценные мне сведения, что некоторые виды насекомых
> встречаются на определенных цветах (М. М. Пришвин, 1925).
>
> Прощаясь со мною, пианист сказал мне, что мои слова ценны ему лишь по
> отношению к музыке, т. к. живописью он не занимается. (П. Н. Филонов,
> 1930-е).
>
> Литература теперь ценна ему не сама по себе, а тем, что дает
> возможность «жить почти свободным человеком, наслаждаться уединением,
> питающим любовь к человеку, зверю, цветку и всему» (Алексей Варламов,
> 2002).
>
> Они ценны нам прежде всего потому, что несут на себе не только тонкий
> флер «серебряного века» (Александр Алексеев, 2003).
>
> В Брюсове ценна нам здоровая исключительность (Андрей Белый, 1908).
>
> ...Повторенная униженность (и некая новая мысль в ней) была мне ценна.
> (Владимир Маканин, 1997).
>
> Может, поняли теперь, почему мне ценны звонки, приносящие оживление в
> мою глупую жизнь? (Г. С. Эфрон, 1941).
>
> ...Мне ценнее, конечно, отзыв, напечатанный в Полном собрании
> сочинений Владимира Соловьева (С. М. Волконский, 1922).
>
> В этих пейзажах, однако, скрыто огромное индивидуальное усилие за
> свободу, и тем, только тем они мне ценны до сих пор (М. М. Пришвин,
> 1925).
>
> ...В его доме я провел много приятных вечеров, особенно мне ценных
> вследствие почти полного отсутствия знакомств (А. Ф. Редигер, 1918).
>
> Мне ценны мгновения, ей века… (М. М. Пришвин, 1914).
>
> Высвечивается: им ценно то, какими они были (Н. В. Кожевникова, 2003).
>
> Ему ценно в них именно начало личное. (Д. В. Философов, 1908).
>
> Победы давались нелегко, но тем они были нам ценнее (Н. К. Рерих,
> 1944).
>
> Не темы фольклора представляются нам ценными, но возврат души... (В.
> И. Иванов, 1908).

Comment: *и даже объясняется, по каким причинам эта вариативность со временем возрастает* Дали бы основное. Хотя бы тезисно или цитатой. А то я пока не могу связать это вариативноность с той "объективностью", о которой автор спрашивает.

Comment: @behemothus Я зря назвал своё сообщение ответом. Это был расширенный комментарий по поводу управления прилагательного "ценный", не более того. Сейчас я это поправлю.

Comment: Ой... Да я ж не об этом совсем. Мне действительно хочется понять, откуда там "вариативность" растет у Глазуновой и как это связано с вопросом. Если связано вообще..

Comment: Спасибо за цитаты!

Answer (score 3):

Второй ответ (это не ошибка, так говорится намеренно)

1. ***Нам ценно ваше мнение***,  а вы сами-то как ***нам*** дороги!  Не ***для нас***, а именно – ***нам***.

***Для нас*** – это где-то рядом, вокруг. Это не настоящая близость,  а пограничная, на расстоянии.  А ***нам*** – это теплота, задушевность, сердечность,  это наше отношение к вам. Вы ***нам*** нужны, а не ***для нас*** нужны.

Слова, с помощью которых люди выражают отзывчивость, неравнодушие, искренность и доверие, — это слова любви, и они здесь **очень кстати**.

2. Так что не ошибка это, **а маркетинговый ход, воздействие на эмоции.** Это только сначала форма нам  будет казаться странной и чересчур  субъективной, а  потом, возможно, станет привычной.

Область применения Д.п. – это **направленность** действия или признака  **непосредственно на предмет** (*милый **сердцу**,  дорогой **мне**, ценный **нам**, а не для нас*).

В 19 веке, а также в первой трети 20 века форма Д.п.  вообще применялась значительно чаще.  *Хозяйка дому,  отец солдатам, корень злу, душа всем мыслям и делам*  –  такие сочетания практически перестали употребляться.

А  обращенность признака  непосредственно к лицу – это выглядело  как-то **индивидуально и чересчур эмоционально** в тот период,  когда ценилось всё только общее. Неправильно выглядело, другими словами. Однако  сейчас ситуация может измениться.

Comment: Спасибо, очень интересно!

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, здесь проявляется проблема *сочетаемости*: "***нам** интересно" ваше мнение*, но *"**для нас** ценно*"; результат "*хороший **для нас***", но "*понятный **нам***". Для "ценный/ценен" встречаются такие отклонения: "*матери-истории ценен*" (Маяковский); "*ценен Богу*" (религиозные тексты), но это специфический стиль, абсолютизирующий (для самой истории, для Бога) качество "ценный".

Answer (score 2):

Правильным будет вариант:  ***Для нас очень ценно ваше мнение.***

**1. Об  объективности оценки**

В Нацкорпусе  можно найти 38 примеров с **направленным значением** признака (ценный для кого-либо):

Содержание шекспировских сонетов **ценно для нас** не только само по себе, но и тем, что оно сходно с содержанием остальных его произведений. [М. М. Морозов (1948)]

Это полотенце вот уже шестьдесят лет сопровождает меня на моем жизненном пути и весьма **ценно для меня** как воспоминание о моей любимой сестре. [В. Лихоносов. (1983)]

А самое главное, в теннисе много тактических комбинаций , что **ценно для людей,** умеющих думать.  [Шамиль Тарпищев. (1999)]

**2. Выбор падежа**

Проверить управление для прилагательного ***ценный***  можно по словарю.

Слово ***ценный*** здесь имеет значение «важный», а это прилагательное управляет Р.п.: ***важный для нас***.  Близкое по смыслу прилагательное  ***дорогой*** в значении «важный» также управляет Р.п.: ***дорогой для нас*** .

Кроме того,  оно может управлять  Д.п. (***дорогой нам***), но в значении «милый, любимый, близкий сердцу», а этого значения у слова  «ценный» нет (оно не указано в словаре). Вероятно, именно этим можно объяснить речевую ошибку.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (словари и примеры)

**У Кузнецова:**

**ЦЕННЫЙ**,  1. только полн. Имеющий цену, обладающий стоимостью. Ц. бумаги. 2. Стоящий больших денег, дорогой. Ц. подарок.  3. **Имеющий важное, существенное значение.** Ц-ая мысль, идея.  4. Такой, которым дорожат, очень нужный. Ц. работник.

**ДОРОГОЙ**,  1. Имеющий высокую цену, стоящий больших денег 2. Такой, которым дорожат; **важный, ценный для кого-, чего-л.**; нужный, необходимый.  4. **Милый, любимый, близкий сердцу.**   Родной город **дорог моей душе.**

**ВАЖНЫЙ,**  1. **(для кого-чего).** Имеющий особенно большое значение, значительный, существенный. . В-ое для науки направление. В. для себя вывод.

**У Ефремовой:**

ЦЕННЫЙ, 1. Имеющий высокую цену, выраженную в денежных единицах. || Имеющий высокую стоимость; дорогой. 2. Имеющий объявленную ценность I 1. (о посылке, письме и т.п.). II прил. 1. Имеющий **важное значение**. 2. Такой, которым дорожат. 3. Очень нужный, полезный.

**Всего два примера из Нацкорпуса** (Д.п., значение "дорого мне")

**Ценно нам**, русским, видеть, как быстро растет осознание мощи нашего народа. [Н. К. Рерих. Листы, не вошедшие во II том (1941)]

Многие даже испугались, когда Игорь Северянин написал: "Я повсеградно оэкранен, Я повсесердно утвержден". Я же всегда был сторонником такого наречия, и уже лет десять твержу, что оно и законно, и неизбежно, **и ценно мне**; особенно дорого то, что такие же тенденции речи наблюдаются и языке детей.  [К. И. Чуковский. Эгофутуристы (1922)]

Comment: Sharon, подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком словаре управления Вы смотрели?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в дополнении к ответу.

Comment: Спасибо, я понял. А у Шведовой управление прилагательного "важный" тоже вариативное (кому-чему-н. — для кого-чего-н.). Но "Русская грамматика" вышла 40 лет тому, может, она уже устарела в этой части.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, суть вопроса в том, может ли вообще мнение быть ценным — в принципе и в конкретном контексте. Вариативность же и прочая грамматика тут, видимо, не во главе угла.

Так вот на первую часть вопроса: однозначно да. На вторую — тоже да, но с некоторыми пояснениями.

~1. Ценность сама по себе вещь, которая может быть вполне субъективная. Помните у Маяковского "кто более матери-истории ценен?" Ну явно же не объективную оценку имел в виду певец социализма... Грамматику этой краткой формы, возможно, есть смысл поисследовать. Создается впечатление, что краткая форма тут несколько меняет смысл... Но не более. По сути вопросов быть не должно.

~2. А вот смысл фразы, высказываемой ныне телефонными барышнями XXI века, нуждается, видимо, в пояснениях. Я пока склоняюсь к тому, что "Для нас ценно мнение" и "Нам ценно мнение" оба имеют право на жизнь, но имеют несколько разный смысл. "Нам ценно" — это то, что у нас есть, что мы храним. "Мне ценны мои воспоминания". "Для меня ценно" — это то, что я сейчас только что получил или могу получить.
Поэтому в контексте мнения, если оно только что получено, вернее будет сказать "для меня".

*Все это пока в рамках частного мнения, не имею возможности провести содержательный анализ. Да и цитат крайне мало.*

(+)
Если, действуя в духе Sharon, поменять "ценно" на "важно" (а еще "мнение" — на "соображения" или даже "информацию"), то ситуация будет действительно много проще и понятнее. Но насколько такая замена корректна?!

Comment: Видимо, я не очень понятно высказался в вопросе, но я не сомневался в том, что мнение может быть ценно. То есть "мы ценим ваше мнение" у меня не вызывало никаких вопросов.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой мда... Ну извините тогда. Пора мне на переподготовку, совсем перестал других понимать... (((..  Хотя яуж тоже не так в лоб понял... У вас же не просто ценность мнения, а некая "объективность" присутвует... То есть я отвечал на вопрос "обязана ли ценность (некая - и конкретно  ценность мнения) быть объективной. Опять не так?

Comment: Перечитал и понял, что действительно сам себе противоречу. Простите! То есть в тот момент я подумал, что что-то ценное может быть независимо от мнения конкретных людей. Правда, потом, смотрю, я **усомнился в здравости** своей мысли, написал, что могу **ошибаться** и что тогда можно сказать "мы ценим" (ваше/твоё мнение). Можно было бы убрать фразу про объективность, но тогда придётся и конец убирать. Ещё раз простите, что ввёл  вас в заблуждение!